# Should stats.norm.pdf gives same result as stats.gaussian_kde in Python?

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, scipy, probability-density

I was trying to estimate PDF of 1-D using `gaussian_kde`. However, when I plot pdf using `stats.norm.pdf`, it gives me different result. Please correct me if I am wrong, I think they should give quite similar result. Here's my code.

```
        npeaks = 9
        mean = np.array([0.2, 0.3, 0.38, 0.55, 0.65,0.7,0.75,0.8,0.82]) #peak locations
        support = np.arange(0,1.01,0.01)
        std = 0.03
        pkfun = sum(stats.norm.pdf(support, loc=mean[i], scale=std) for i in range(0,npeaks))

        df = pd.DataFrame(support)
        X = df.iloc[:,0]

        min_x, max_x = X.min(), X.max()

        plt.figure(1)
        plt.plot(support,pkfun)

        kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(X)

        grid = 100j
        X= np.mgrid[min_x:max_x:grid]

        Z = np.reshape(kernel(X), X.shape)
        # plot KDE
        plt.figure(2)
        plt.plot(X, Z) 
        plt.show()
```

Also, when I get the first derivative of `stats.gaussian_kde` was far from the original signal. However, the result of first derivative of `stats.norm.pdf` does make sense. So, I am assuming I might have error in my code above.

Value of  X= np.mgrid[min_x:max_x:grid]:

```
[

 0.          0.01010101  0.02020202  0.03030303  0.04040404  0.05050505
  0.06060606  0.07070707  0.08080808  0.09090909  0.1010101   0.11111111
  0.12121212  0.13131313  0.14141414  0.15151515  0.16161616  0.17171717
  0.18181818  0.19191919  0.2020202   0.21212121  0.22222222  0.23232323
  0.24242424  0.25252525  0.26262626  0.27272727  0.28282828  0.29292929
  0.3030303   0.31313131  0.32323232  0.33333333  0.34343434  0.35353535
  0.36363636  0.37373737  0.38383838  0.39393939  0.4040404   0.41414141
  0.42424242  0.43434343  0.44444444  0.45454545  0.46464646  0.47474747
  0.48484848  0.49494949  0.50505051  0.51515152  0.52525253  0.53535354
  0.54545455  0.55555556  0.56565657  0.57575758  0.58585859  0.5959596
  0.60606061  0.61616162  0.62626263  0.63636364  0.64646465  0.65656566
  0.66666667  0.67676768  0.68686869  0.6969697   0.70707071  0.71717172
  0.72727273  0.73737374  0.74747475  0.75757576  0.76767677  0.77777778
  0.78787879  0.7979798   0.80808081  0.81818182  0.82828283  0.83838384
  0.84848485  0.85858586  0.86868687  0.87878788  0.88888889  0.8989899
  0.90909091  0.91919192  0.92929293  0.93939394  0.94949495  0.95959596
  0.96969697  0.97979798  0.98989899  1.        ]
```

Value of X = df.iloc[:,0]:

```
[ 0.    0.01  0.02  0.03  0.04  0.05  0.06  0.07  0.08  0.09  0.1   0.11
  0.12  0.13  0.14  0.15  0.16  0.17  0.18  0.19  0.2   0.21  0.22  0.23
  0.24  0.25  0.26  0.27  0.28  0.29  0.3   0.31  0.32  0.33  0.34  0.35
  0.36  0.37  0.38  0.39  0.4   0.41  0.42  0.43  0.44  0.45  0.46  0.47
  0.48  0.49  0.5   0.51  0.52  0.53  0.54  0.55  0.56  0.57  0.58  0.59
  0.6   0.61  0.62  0.63  0.64  0.65  0.66  0.67  0.68  0.69  0.7   0.71
  0.72  0.73  0.74  0.75  0.76  0.77  0.78  0.79  0.8   0.81  0.82  0.83
  0.84  0.85  0.86  0.87  0.88  0.89  0.9   0.91  0.92  0.93  0.94  0.95
  0.96  0.97  0.98  0.99  1.  ]
```

Comment: Can you post your data (`X`)?

Comment: I updated the post with X value

Comment: Could you in brief explain what your purpose of comparing?

Comment: Initially I want to get the number of Zero crossings and I have 3D data, so I got estimated pdf using gaussian_kde and then I got first derivative, and I noticed that whatever the data I have, I got number of peaks =9. So I did the above example as proof of concepts to the same idea since I know exactly the number of peaks in my data, but in 3D data I don't. When I got first derivative of  the output of stats.norm.pdf the result is similar to the number of peaks data and the shape of the pdf. However, making derivative to the gaussian_kde gives constant result regardless the data input

Comment: The raws:
`grid = 100j
#X= np.mgrid[min_x:max_x:grid]
#Z = np.reshape(kernel(X), X.shape)`

Has no effect at all in this situation. I double checked it. 
I just wrote it, because perhaps this is a reason of unexpected results you got.
As I could figure out you calculate the gaussian base of a pritty linear data, so it is straightforward that will get a standard U-shape. The pdf stats however are calculated sequentially base of the separated element of the peek set successively. Why do you even expect similar result, please explain.

Comment: So how can I plot KDE of the original data without testing it on another data populated based on range of the original data ?

Comment: OK maybe I found: Just tried to find an error in your code: 

`kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(X)` pass `X` as argument initializing the class. 

Then `plt.plot(X, kernel(X)) ` pass `X` as argument. This is usually doesn't a proper thing in Python.
As I wrote in the source code as example:
`kernel = stats.gaussian_kde(values) 
 Z = np.reshape(kernel(positions).T, X.shape)`
So as you can see, you have to first initialize KDE with **DATA, i.e.values** then to call with **positions**.
But you initialized and called both with data.

Comment: But, again I want the output of KDE of original X not positions, so I can make first derivative on the output of KDE. That's why I did kernel(X). I'd prefer if you could write an answer with your supported code to plot pdf output vs KDE of original data and save the output of KDE to apply first derivative on it

Comment: I got you now, then it is not a mistake that the values of `df` are exactly the same as the generated values of `support`?

Comment: They are the same, check line df = pd.DataFrame(support)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84734/discussion-between-george-solymosi-and-carmen).

Answer (score 0):

In the row below you make pdf calculations in every peak-point along 100 datapoints with the `std = 0,03`. So you get a matrix with array with **100 elements per row** then you **summerize** it **elementwise**, **result:**
[image]

Thus you get a graph with 9 narrow -because of `std = 0,03`- U-shape.
Are you sure, that this was your purpose with this row?

This will never get the similar graph as the kernel estimate base of the original data, **result:**
[image]

> pkfun = sum(stats.norm.pdf(support, loc=mean[i], scale=std) for i in
>   range(0,npeaks))